# How does the concept of repeat mode works

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, logic, repeat

In the project (in codeigniter) I am working, a user can create a task and set its repeat mode as (Once/Daily/Weekly) where
**Daily** - Task will appear for the same time everyday in future
**Weekly** - Task will appear every Monday (say if task is being added on Monday)
**Once** - Task will get added only for today

Now every task created by user creates a record in database,

For example, suppose a task is created today(13-01-2014) from 2:00-3:00 with repeat mode as `Daily`, this will create a record against this `(13-01-2014)` date but I can't add the same task at that time for all future dates.

And also user can change/edit the mode of task anytime then that should not repeat thereafter.

Can anyone plz explain me the concept of how this repeating mode works? I mean when actually to create a task for future dates, or how to maintain the same in database.

Answer (score 0):

"Explain the concept of *repeat mode*" is a pretty vague request. However, I think I understand what piece is missing.

I assume you have some kind of `taskId`, which is a unique key for each task. What you need is a `batchId` as well. Your end result would look something like this:

```
+----------+----------+----------------------+
|taskId    |batchId   |description           |
|----------|----------|----------------------|
|        1 |          | Some meeting         |
|        2 |          | Another meeting      |
|        3 |       1  | Daily meeting        |
|        4 |       1  | Daily meeting        |
|        5 |       1  | Daily meeting        |
|        6 |       2  | Go to the gym!       |
|        7 |       2  | Go to the gym!       |
|        8 |       2  | Go to the gym!       |
|        9 |       2  | Go to the gym!       |
|       10 |          | Yet another meeting  |
+----------+----------+----------------------+
```

Having a `batchId` lets you group these events in the case you need to modify all the tasks at once, but still lets you modify each task individually if need be, thanks to the `taskId`.

---

The actual implementation of this `batchId` is up to you. For example, it can be:

- a random string generated on-the-fly
- a hash of the first `taskId` to ensure that their always unique
- a foreign key in a separate table that auto-generates a `batchId` as its key

Use the one that best suits your needs, or make one up yourself.

---

I just made up `taskId` and `batchId`. Replace those with whatever makes sense to you.